# passing method parameter to nested composite component fails

Tags: jsf, methods, nested, composite

I have a problem with passing method parameters to nested composite component.

I have a first component wose composite:interface looks like :

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="onRowEditListener" required="false" method-signature="void listener(org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent)"/>
</composite:interface>
```

It uses another composite component component which has a similar interface.

The first level component is used this way :

```
<mynamespace:compo1 onRowEditListener=#{bean.method}"/>
```

The nested one is used this way :

```
<mynamespace:compo2 onRowEditListener=#{cc.attrs.onRowEditListener}"/>
```

If I insert  in both controls, I got :

- in the first level control, an output like org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl@358f0647, which looks good to me
- in the second (nested) level control, an output like org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.LocationValueExpression@ff381f45 .

Raised exception looks like :

```
19/07/2012 19:39:02 fr.senat.faces.exceptions.DetailedExceptionHandler INFO  [DetailedExceptionHandler.java:40] [http-8080-7] - Stack trace: javax.faces.FacesException: Exception while calling broadcast on component : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /editSenateur.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_5][Class: org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout,Id: j_id_6][Class: org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnit,Id: j_id_v][Class: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel,Id: detailCommissions][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: j_id_x][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView,Id: tabFonctionsInternes][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab,Id: fonctionsCommissions][Class: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer,Id: j_id_10][Class: javax.faces.component.UIPanel,Id: j_idj_id_10__f_cc_facet][Class: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel,Id: panelTabViewCommissions][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView,Id: tabViewCommissions][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab,Id: commissionTab][Class: org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGrid,Id: j_id_15][Class: org.primefaces.component.row.Row,Id: j_id_1b][Class: org.primefaces.component.column.Column,Id: j_id_1c][Class: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer,Id: j_id_1d][Class: javax.faces.component.UIPanel,Id: j_idj_id_1d__f_cc_facet][Class: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable,Id: sheetFonctions]} created from: /resources/sen/fonctionsCommission.xhtml at line 27 and column 162
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:430)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1610)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1596)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1596)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1596)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1023)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1360)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.execute(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:95)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at fr.senat.faces.filters.HibernateSessionConversationFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionConversationFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:42)
    at org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent.processListener(RowEditEvent.java:41)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:74)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:406)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:195)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ValueExpressionMethodExpression.invoke(ValueExpressionMethodExpression.java:68)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    ... 38 more
```

It looks like the method is properly passed to the first control, but that the EL expression gets a bullet when passed to the second...

I am using :

- MyFaces 2.1.7
- Tomcat 6.0.33

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

The only "progress" I can assess is a kludge...

The kludge class :

```
/**
 * 
 * @author lpenet
 * 
 *         This class is a workaround kluge. Methods passed as a parameter to a
 *         composite component then to a PrimeFaces p:ajax seems to get a bullet
 *         somewhere in the process, at least with Tomcat 6 + MyFaces
 *         2.1 + CODI 1.0.5 + OpenWebbeans 1.0.3 See :
 *         http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23558&p=72885#p72885
 * 
 *         Using this class as "componentType", one can forward the methode call.
 *
 *         Not so nice, but... works.
 * 
 */
@FacesComponent(value = "fr.senat.beans.PrimefacesListenerKludge")
public class PrimefacesListenerKludge extends UINamingContainer {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return "javax.faces.NamingContainer"; // Important! Required for
                                                // composite components.
    }

    public void forwardRowEditListener(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Object listener = getAttributes().get("onRowEditListener");
        if (listener == null) {
            return;
        }
        MethodExpression ajaxEventListener = (MethodExpression) listener;
        ajaxEventListener
                .invoke(context.getELContext(), new Object[] { event });
    }
}
```

Sample use :

```
<composite:interface componentType="fr.senat.beans.PrimefacesListenerKludge">
        ...
    <composite:attribute name="onRowEditListener" required="false"
        method-signature="void listener(org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent)"
        default="#{cc.parent.attrs.onRowEditListener}" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
        ...
    </composite:implementation>
```

To be honest, I do not know if it is still required with my current stack (PrimeFaces 4/MyFaces 2.1.13/OWB 1.2.1/Tomcat 7.0.32) but lacks the time to test.

Comment: Please let us know when you made progress with this.